# no output to disk implementing xor encryption in c

Tags: c, encryption, xor

I have an odd problem: The following code is meant to implement xor encryption, but I am having trouble debugging why nothing is written to the disk. I am thinking I am using `fseek` or `fputc` improperly. The following is a working example of my issue. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *key, *data;
    char keyf[] = "/sdcard/key";
    char dataf[128];
    int c0, c1, c2;
    long int i;

    key = fopen(keyf, "r+");
    if (key == NULL) {
        printf("%s missing\n", keyf);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("data file:\n");
    i = 0;
    while ((c0 = getc(stdin)) != '\n' &&
           i < 128)
        dataf[i++] = (char)c0;
    data = fopen(dataf, "r");
    if (data == NULL) {
        printf("%s missing\n", dataf);
        exit(2);
    }
    i = 0;
    while ((c0 = fgetc(key)) != EOF &&
           (c1 = fgetc(data)) != EOF) {
        while (!c0) c0 = fgetc(key);
        c2 = c0 ^ c1;
        fseek(data, i++, SEEK_SET);
        fputc(c2, data);
        printf("%c", c2);
    }
    fflush(data);
    fclose(key);
    fclose(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've opened `data` as read-only. You will need to open it for read-write, and you don't want truncation, so you will want mode `"r+"`, which opens the file for reading/writing with the position at the start for both.. As you read from the file, the file pointer will be incrementing, so to write back over the character you just read, you will also need to seek with `fseek()` to go back.

[Here is a link to the fopen man page which describes access modes.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)

[This is the fseek man page which will describe how to move your file position around.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html)

Comment: I knew it had to be simple. I was opening the "key" file as I wanted to open the "data" file. Thanks.

Comment: Good point about `"r+"`. I'm going to revise my answer to use that mode. `"a+"` would work, too, I think, but the write pointer will append.